# Modify POST variable names in function

Tags: jquery, function

I have a function that posts data to a script and it updates a database but the script uses a for loop to increment a number and that number is inserted into a variable name on the script. The reason for this is that I am pulling an unknown amount of data and I need to uniquely identify the cells.

So the issue I'm having involves a function and wanting to modify the post variables so the script can check for them in the loop.

Ex.

```
function test(test_name, test_id, cell_num, type)
  {
     if (type == "Test") {
         var test_name = $("#test_"+cell_num+"_name").val();
         $.post('test.php', { cell_num: cell_num, 'test_'+cell_num+'_name': test_name });
     }
  }
```

You'll notice 'test'+cell_num+'_name': test_name is formatted incorrectly. What I'm attempting to do is introduce a variable variable name as my script loops through these names incrementally.

UPDATE:

```
     var test_name = $("#test_"+cell_num+"_name").val();
     var params = {};
     params['cell_'+cell_num] = cell_num;
     params['test_'+cell_num+'_name'] = test_name;
     $.post('test.php', params);
```

I am unable to access the data in params on test.php by using

```
test_name = $_POST['test_1_name'];
cell = $_POST['cell_1'];
```

It seems params is passing on the values and not the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with a standard post and dropped the usage of dynamic variables as it was causing to much unnecessary stress. It was being used for an inventory system so you can modify a single field and as soon as you click away the single cell would update the database.

I was trying to reduce the amount of traffic to the database but it was too much of a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
function test(test_name, test_id, cell_num, type)
  {
     if (type == "Test") {
         var test_name = $("#test_"+cell_num+"_name").val();
         var params = {cell_num: cell_num};
         params['test_'+cell_num+'_name'] = test_name;
         $.post('test.php', params);
     }
  }
```

While defining a json object, you cant define the key name dynamically. So when you need dynamic keys, treat it like array and it will fix your problem.

Comment: While defining a json object, you cant define the key name dynamically. So when you need dynamic keys, do it like array key.

Comment: @HasinHayder - if you have a reason why this should work better, then please put that in your answer.  Answers are much more valuable to all if they explain why they fix something.

Comment: I'm not sure who decided to try to retaliate against me by downvoting a bunch of my other answers, but I am not the downvote on this question (I actually upvoted it once I understood why it was a correct answer).

Comment: Interesting. So is params['test_'+cell_num+'_name'] = test_name; inserting a new parameter into the post? If so am I to assume it will be understood as test_1_name: test_name?

Comment: @DevinRawlek you are right. But you are not allowed to do that in the first place because Javascript doesn't allow you do define dynamic key in the {} json block. So this is the workaround. But ultimately, the "params" will still remain as a json object.

Comment: @HasinHayder That makes sense. I would like to make var params = {cell_num: cell_num}; dynamic as well but am not able to define params properly. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: That's not possible :) But my code outputs exactly the same data for http POST.

Comment: So i can't do this?

var params = {};
params['cell_'+cell_num] = cell_num;
params['test_'+cell_num+'_name'] = test_name;

Comment: By the way, if an answer solves your problem then please select it as correct answer @DevinRawlek

Comment: @HasinHayder I've not been able to retrieve the variable data by using $_POST['test_1_name']; It doesn't look like params is passing the variable names, just their values.